Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type in reduce function
I need to group objects by the value of a given key:
[
    { name: 'name-1', foo: 'bar' },
    { name: 'name-2', foo: 'bar' }
]

Results in:
{ 
    'bar': [
        { name: 'name-1', foo: 'bar' },
        { name: 'name-2', foo: 'bar' }
    ]
}

Therefore I'm using this reduce function:
const groupBy = (
  array: Array<Record<string, any>>,
  key: string
): Record<string, any> => {
  return array.reduce(
    (result: Record<string, any>, currentValue: Record<string, string>) => {
      ;(result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
        currentValue
      )
      return result
    },
    {}
  )
}

I am using a very strict typescript and I do get the error Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. for currentValue and key. I tried to solve this, but I failed. So maybe someone has a good input for me...

@AlanOmar You see the error if you turn on the compiler option noUncheckedIndexedAccess

I think the problem is from the Record utility type when you set noUncheckedIndexedAccess It add undefined to Record so you have to guard against undefined in each property access.

here is updated link

Instead of reduce, you can use groupBy function.

The Object.groupBy() static method groups the elements of a given iterable according to the string values returned by a provided callback function.

Object.groupBy(items, callbackFn);

It is supported by all major browsers (currently 84% support)
So, in you case something like this:


let itemsToBeGrouped = [
    { name: 'name-1', foo: 'bar' },
    { name: 'name-2', foo: 'bar' }
]

const grouppedItems = Object.groupBy(itemsToBeGrouped, ({foo})=>foo)
console.log(grouppedItems)




Note that Object.groupBy() isn't standardized yet and risks being removed anytime (as with its predecessor Array#group()).
